# fix "out of range" monitor error while installing ubuntu 22

Tags: dual-boot, monitor

i tried to install Ubuntu 22 on my old computer
on instantiation screen when i select try/install Ubuntu 22 i will see monitor error "out of range"
When I press enter, the error message disappears and the black screen will appear 
i followed this guide [Out of range on monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048905/out-of-range-on-monitor#comment1714065_1048905) but can't find `set gfxmode=` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file 
im using windows , any idea ?

Comment: Ubuntu 22, so you're asking about a Ubuntu Core 22 system?  That was intended to be used *headless* without screens/monitors.  Don't forget 22 is a specialist *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server.

Comment: To be clear this error is on a Windows machine before Ubuntu is installed?

Comment: @David yes windows is installed and i went to install Ubuntu 22 desktop Alongside With Windows

Comment: So this error is coming from a Windows machine which makes it off topic on this site. You need to address this Windows issue and then install Ubuntu. If Ubuntu is not installed there is no grub file, that is part of a installed Ubuntu system.

Comment: @David i write Ubuntu 22 desktop iso file into usb device  and boot system form it , I don't think this problem has anything to do with the windows

Comment: Are you sure there is no "set gfxmode" line in your grub.cfg script? It looks like this on my Ubuntu 22:
`if loadfont $font ; then set gfxmode=auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hi 
i found my answers 
to fix this problem you should select Ubuntu (safe graphic) in grab menu while trying to install Ubuntu 
After selecting second option you will see black screen for few minute (based on your USB drive speed) and then Ubuntu install window will appear

Answer (score 0):

The linked guide refers to someone who already has Ubuntu installed, so you wouldn't be able to find the settings if you have yet to install Ubuntu.

To proceed with the install and avoid the black screen and error message, **BEFORE** you try to select the option "Try Ubuntu..." or "Install Ubuntu", pres <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up `Other Options` and then use the keyboard to select `nomodeset` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> to select the option, then try running install or "Trying Ubunutu".

If that still does not resolve the issue, do the same steps again but this time after selecting `nomodeset` hit <kbd>F6</kbd> again and then also select `acpi=off` to see if that works. This setting is not necessarily ideal for laptops because of its role in power management but if it can get you through the install, then any updates Ubuntu finds should hopefully address that. But you may want, either before attempting the install or after you've had success with the install (*hopefully*), to try checking if your laptop has a BIOS update since you did mention it was an older laptop (*though "older" can be subjective*).

Once it is installed, you can follow the guide you linked by entering Ubuntu in recovery mode if the issue persists following installation or following a BIOS update. And, in case it wasn't something you already checked, try changing system to UEFI mode if it's not in UEFI mode already. I just wouldn't recommend trying to do the grub configurations through Windows, in case that's what you had meant when you tried searching for it and you were using Windows.